# value of the infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone help me evaluate the following infinite series: $$\sum_{m=5}^\infty  \frac{3}{m^2+3m+2}$$

I have tried expanding out some initial terms of this series to get a sense of where it will converge but in vain.

If someone can explain how to go about evaluating infinite series like this (which does not follow a geometric sequence), it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $m = 5$ instead of $i = 5$?

Comment: You can use$\displaystyle\frac{3}{m^2+3m+2}=3\,\left(\frac1{m+1}-\frac1{m+2}\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{m=5}^{n}\frac{3}{m^2+3m+2}
&=\sum_{m=5}^{n}3\left(\frac{1}{m+1}-\frac{1}{m+2}\right)\\
&=3\left(\frac16-\frac17+\frac17-\frac18+\frac18-\frac19+\ldots+\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)\\
&=3\left(\frac16-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)\\
&=\frac12-\frac{3}{n+2}
\end{align}

Infinite case is just $\frac12$

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: $$m^{2}+3m+2 = (m+1)(m+2)$$

Hint 2:

> Decompose your fraction into partial fractions using hint 1. You should then get a telescoping series.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\sum_{m=5}^n\frac{3}{m^2+3m+2}=\frac{n-4}{2(n+2)}$$ this can be proved by induction

Comment: This is a very good **hint**, for sure !

Comment: this provide definitively an answer to the quesion, i know this sentences

Comment: Lol, @SahibaArora why this do not provide an answer to the question. Btw Sir Dr. Sonnhard, I do not see any hint here. You may delete the word "Hint", then it is fine I think.

Comment: "this can be proved by induction" Yes, if one wants to avoid understanding why the formula holds, one can use induction. Or, one may want to actually do some maths and start with @ProfessorVector's comment on main...